# bean not getting created even after using @entity

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, jpa, javabeans

I am not able to run my Spring Boot application, because there is an issue with JPA. But I am not able to find the problem and resolve it. I searched for a solution on several stack overflow topics, but not even one solution was helpful for me. I defined the following model:

code of my entity class-

```
package com.ncu.legalVise.entities;



import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;


@Entity
@Table(name ="users")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Users {

    
//  public Users(String username, String password, int enabled) {
//      super();
//      this.username = username;
//      this.password = password;
//      this.enabled = enabled;
//  }
//
//  public Users() {
//      super();
//  }

    @Id
    private String username;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int enabled;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public int getEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    public void setEnabled(int enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

    
    
}
```

My pom file -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.ncu</groupId>
    <artifactId>LegalVise</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>LegalVise</name>
    <description>Legal Vise</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            
        </dependency>
                <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

my controller -

```
package com.ncu.legalVise.controller;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.ncu.legalVise.entities.Authorities;
import com.ncu.legalVise.entities.Users;
import com.ncu.legalVise.repository.AuthoritiesRepository;
import com.ncu.legalVise.repository.UsersRepository;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/public/security")
public class SecurityController {
    
    Users user;
    Authorities authority;
    UsersRepository usersRepository;
    AuthoritiesRepository authoritiesRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    SecurityController(Users user, Authorities authority,UsersRepository usersRepository,AuthoritiesRepository authoritiesRepository)
    {
        user = this.user;
        authority= this.authority;
        usersRepository=this.usersRepository;
        authoritiesRepository=this.authoritiesRepository;
        
    }
    @PostMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> register(@RequestBody String userName, @RequestBody String password, @RequestBody String authorities)
    {
        user.setUsername(userName);
        user.setPassword(password);
        user.setEnabled(1);
        authority.setUsername(userName);
        authority.setAuthority(authorities);
        if(!usersRepository.existsById(userName))
        {
            usersRepository.save(user);
            authoritiesRepository.save(authority);
            return ResponseEntity.ok(usersRepository.findById(userName));
        }
        return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
    }
}
```

the error message -

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.ncu.legalVise.controller.SecurityController required a bean of type 'com.ncu.legalVise.entities.Users' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.ncu.legalVise.entities.Users' in your configuration.

kindly help me solve this

i tried changing dependencies but nothing worked

Comment: It appears spring RUNTIME does not know the package is there, perhaps if it is "jar" ed the packaging mechanism is not aware of either the class or the code package to jar package. it probably could not pick up either the class file itself or the whole package for entities during buils.

Comment: Entities are not beans.  They are runtime pojo's that hold data from a database.

Comment: yes , i agree with you but the error shows bean not found, how should i handle that?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are targeting SpringBoot 3, you should change from `javax.persistence` to `jakarta.persistence` imports in your `Users` class.

SpringBoot 3 major change is the adoption of JakartaEE 9 (with dropping jdk8 / jdk11 support to have jdk17 baseline), which leads to have to migrate from `javax` to `jakarta` for many JavaEE feature, including JPA.

Since your code compile, I'd also suggest to clean up your `pom.xml` to remove old JPA dependencies in order to drop `javax.persistence` recognized package (and so old JavaEE8 jpa support).

Answer (score 0):

Based on version of `spring-boot`(3.2.0) that you are using I see some miss configuration to fix it

Remove next one dependency from `pom.xml`

```
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.0-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Also be sure that you will do replace in your project on imports from `javax.` to `jakarta.`. More details about it check [preparing-for-spring-boot-3-0](https://spring.io/blog/2022/05/24/preparing-for-spring-boot-3-0)

As an example:
Instead of

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
```

It have to be:

```
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
```